# Assert inside Method inside Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

`using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;`

I need to check a single method in my code a number of times with different inputs. I've set up a unit test that captures this, but I want to simplify my testing by putting the unit test's code into a method that I can call in several unit tests with different parameters.

The problem is this: **assertions in the method inside the unit test don't send their Messages up to the test for me to view.**

Is there any way to fix that by marking my method with something like `[TestMethod]` or do I have to call `Assert` from *directly* inside the unit test?

Comment: What do you mean by *don't send up*? Perhaps you could post sample code and describe what doesn't behaves as you'd expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call Assert from anywhere once you've entered the public method that has [TestMethod].  This includes private methods.

**Example**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAddition(){

testAddition(3,1,2);
testAddition(4,2,2);
testAddition(5,3,2);

}

private void testAddition(int expected, int x,int y){

var actual = x + y;

Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
}
```

Comment: So it seems that you can. I think my problem was just that I hadn't set up my assert correctly. Thanks.